# WCF service, Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-config, wcf-rest

After running F5 on visual studio 2015 c#, it gives the error:
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:56062/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: http://localhost:56062/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:56062/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth'. The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.HTTP GET Error URI: http://localhost:56062/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:56062/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth'. The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.

I know there have been so many questions asking about this, but still haven't found the solution for my case yet.

- web.config

`

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestServiceTest.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints-->
        <!--Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestServiceTest.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

`

- IRestServiceImpl.cs

`
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;

```
namespace RestServiceTest
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRestServiceImpl" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",
            ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate ="auth")]
        ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData);
    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer")]
    public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string details { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Age { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Exp { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Technology { get; set; }
    }

    }
```

`

- RestServiceImpl.svc

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace RestServiceTest
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "RestServiceImpl" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select RestServiceImpl.svc or RestServiceImpl.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        public ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData)
        {
            //Call Bill here
            var data = rData.details.Split('|');
            var response = new ResponseData
            {
                Name = data[0],
                Age = data[1],
                Exp = data[2],
                Technology = data[3]
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: You are making GET request while your "Auth" method only supports "POST". Check WebInvoke(Method="POST", attribute.

Comment: then how may I make this a POST request?

Comment: You have to programmatically fire POST request or you can use Fiddler to fire post request.

Comment: wouldn't "microsoft wcf test client" do the similar thing as fiddler?

Comment: You can not test REST service (one with webHttpBinding binding) using WCF Test client.

Comment: THanks. I am really new on web service and just installed fiddler, could you show me a tutorial or on-line guide of how to use fiddler? I seem to get 405 and 400 result (red) on the left window.... Thanks again!